# load-{$page hook} and returned parameter

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, admin-menu

I am using this code to enqueue scripts and styles to wordpress plugin. This works well, but I am wondering is there some parameter available in my_admin_enqueue_scripts function? Because I would like to
enqueue different scripts per page. I know I can call different function like my_admin_enqueue_scripts, my_admin_enqueue_scripts2, my_admin_enqueue_scripts3 but I would still need to repeat many scripts to enqueue so I would like to know if I can detect on what page I am in my_admin_enqueue_scripts function.

```
    add_action("admin_menu", "my_admin_menu");

    function my_admin_menu(){

        $menu = add_menu_page('Audio Player', 'Audio Player', MY_CAPABILITY, 'my_settings', 'my_settings_page', 'dashicons-playlist-audio');

        $submenu = add_submenu_page('my_settings', __('Audio Player', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), __('Settings', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), MY_CAPABILITY, 'my_settings', 'my_settings_page'); 
        $submenu2 = add_submenu_page('my_settings', __('Audio Player', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), __('Player manager', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), MY_CAPABILITY, 'my_player_manager', 'my_player_manager_page');  

        add_action( 'load-' . $menu, 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
        add_action( 'load-' . $submenu, 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
        add_action( 'load-' . $submenu2, 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );

    }


    function my_admin_enqueue_scripts($param) {

        //is there a $param here?

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
        wp_enqueue_media();

        wp_enqueue_style("spectrum", plugins_url('/css/spectrum.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script("spectrum", plugins_url('/js/spectrum.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));   


            .... other scripts


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `//is there a $param here?`

None, the [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/) you're using does not pass any parameters to the callback.

But you can instead use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) which passes the hook name for the current menu page — the hook name is also saved in the global `$hook_suffix` variable. You can then use [`get_plugin_page_hookname()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_page_hookname/) to get the hook name for a specific menu page and then conditionally enqueue the scripts for your menu pages.

```php
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts( $hook_suffix ) {
    switch ( $hook_suffix ) {
        // Enqueue scripts for the "Audio Player -> Settings" page.
        case get_plugin_page_hookname( 'my_settings', '' ) :
            //wp_enqueue_script( ... );
        break;

        // Enqueue scripts for the "Audio Player -> Player manager" page.
        case get_plugin_page_hookname( 'my_player_manager', 'my_settings' ) :
            //wp_enqueue_script( ... );
        break;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

And actually, you should use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook for enqueueing admin scripts. :)

Additionally, in your first `add_submenu_page()` call, you should just omit the *sixth* parameter (i.e. the callback) than setting it to `my_settings_page`, to prevent the function from being called twice on the same page.